# control the view access permissions by field.tpl.php in D7

Tags: entities, users

I would like to be able to control who can view a field by a custom field.tpl.php for a given field. Basically I would like to set a coditional at the beginning so that is displays nothing if the user does not have a given role (say, "registered-user").
I would think that this amounts to adding an "if" at the very beginning of the the field template, but I do not have much experience. 
Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: Never put any business logic into tpl files. They can be cached. So unless it's the *"if odd, add class `odd`"* type of logic, it may fail you miserably.

Comment: That's good to know. So my entire approach is mislead? Could you give me a link pointing to somemore info on that?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/user_role_field

Comment: Well, added my own answer as an alternative / complementary to the one by xurshid29

Comment: @Bala I edited your link into my answer, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never put any business logic into tpl files. They can be cached. So unless it's the *"if odd, add class `odd`"* type of logic, it may fail you miserably.

If you need more elaborate rules than [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) give you, you need to implement [`hook_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) in your custom module.

> Return value
>
> TRUE if the operation is allowed, and FALSE if the operation is denied.

[Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module is open source. You can see it's source to learn how this hook is supposed to be used. Same with [User role field](https://drupal.org/project/user_role_field) module. Both are pretty well commented in code, and can serve as good examples how to write your own custom logic. Just make sure you are not forking one, this may lead to more complications than it's worth - if they are not sufficient, inspire and even copy parts of code, but use your own name and info file.

Comment: Cool. I like your answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have much experience in writing a custom code then take a look at [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: That's what I'm using right now, but I'd like to use a logic that is a bit more complex then what it offers. I am also thinking about another level of access control (field-value dependent) by field.tpl.php, so I could as well do that in field template, not in module.

Comment: In fact, what I would like to have is a module that lets me control field access on a per-node basis. Field permissions module lets me define it per field type only.

Comment: @Dalmaz I didn't understand. You want to restrict an access to a field with custom .tpl file or custom module? if you want to a custom implementation of field access then you can use https://drupal.org/project/fieldaccess module. It provides an API function which you can use in you module

Comment: Now I am using the module you mentioned. Ideally, I would like it to work on a per-node basis (not per node - field type), so i thought of stop using it altogether and putting a condition on field.tpl.php.

Comment: Now I use the module. I thought about using code, as the module gives me per-content type control, and I would like to have per - node control. Right now, I use the module you mentioned and Conditional Fields, but the latter is seriously buggy (alpha), so I wanted to try a custom field.tpl.php, which sounds simple. Being able to learn something in the process was also important.

Comment: The other part of my question is at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96866/conditionally-display-a-field-based-on-another-fields-content-by-field-tpl-php